# discord.py: bot doesn't recognize author

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

[image]

When I type !gamer in a channel, this is what the bot responds with

[image]

Although my username is Dairy#6166. To confirm that this is message.author, I had the program print message.author when the code ran:

[image]

Yet the bot still doesn't recognize me and says that I'm not Dairy.

Comment: I just want to add to the already given answers that for serious stuff you shouldnt check for the name of the author but for their id instead using `message.author.id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `message.author` returns a member object ([docs on member object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member)) which, if converted to a string (which is done when you print it) returns the name. So you need to check `message.author.name == "Dairy#6166"` instead of `message.author == "Dairy#6166"`

Also for future questions you might be asking on stackoverflow, please don't just screenshot your code, but copy and paste it to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You must use `message.author.name` instead of `message.author` in your condition phrase.